# How can I pad nullable ints with zeros?

Tags: c#, int, nullable

Is there any way to pad nullable int with zeros the way you can with normal int?

the `myInt.ToString("D3")` doesn't seem to work on nullale ints but for my current project I feel like I need to use nullable `int` in order to get the `null` value in my array instead of 0 as the default.

Comment: Why don't you just use `myInt.Value.ToString("D3")`?

Comment: That does seem to work.  Thank you so much.  I'm still quite a novice at programming so I'm trying to figure things out as I go along.  I'm currently trying work on a project where I start out with an int?[] intArray[50] and if the default value of it is 0 then it would just output as null(blank).  My problem lies in that I want the output(3 digits) to be padded with leading 0's hence the ToString("D3") but I can't quite figure out how to make it so that it will be able to output the format I want as well as the null values if the value is still null.  Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 4):

That is because `int?` is actually `Nullable<T>` where `T` is `int` here.

Calling `ToString` will call that on the `Nullable` struct, not the `int`. `Nullable<T>` has no knowledge of the overloads of `ToString` which `int` has.

You have to get the integer value first:

```
myInt.GetValueOrDefault(0).ToString("D3")
```

Answer (score 2):

An `int` has never leading zeros, it just has a value. A string representation of an `ìnt` can have them. You can use the null-coalescing operator to convert the nullable-int to 0 if it has no value:

```
int? nullableInt = null;
string number = (nullableInt ?? 0).ToString("D3"); // 000
```

or use [`String.PadLeft`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/92h5dc07(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
number = (nullableInt ?? 0).ToString().PadLeft(3, '0');
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to perform that action on the value:

```
myInt.Value.ToString("D3")
```

Example:

```
int? myInt = 3;
Console.WriteLine(myInt.Value.ToString("D3")); // Outputs 003
```

Comment: and what does it output if `myInt` is `null`?

Comment: @TimSchmelter Right, he'll just have to account for that.  My example is not all-inclusive.