# How can I format a variable declared as an int? with a ToString("N0") format?

Tags: c#

I have a variable App.selectedCardCount declared as an int?

and in this code I am having a problem with the .ToString in that it says there is no overload method that takes 1 argument. There is no chance that App.selectedCardCount can be null so is there a way that this could be coded

```
if (App.selectedCardCount == null)
   App.selectedCardCount = App.DB.GetSelectedCardCount();

vm.x = App.selectedCardCount.ToString("N0") + " x ";
```

I also tried this:

```
if (App.selectedCardCount != null)
{
   vm.x = App.selectedCardCount.ToString("N0") + "x";
}
```

So far nothing works so I would appreciate any suggestions.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I pad nullable ints with zeros?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27179656/how-can-i-pad-nullable-ints-with-zeros)

Comment: The int is stored in the `Value` property: `App.selectedCardCount.Value.ToString("N0")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even though your logic ensures it's not a `null` value at runtime, it can't determine that at compile time. The nullable types have two properties you could take advantage of though - [HasValue](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.nullable-1.hasvalue?view=netframework-4.7.2) and [Value](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.nullable-1.value?view=netframework-4.7.2).

```
if (!App.selectedCardCount.HasValue)
   App.selectedCardCount = App.DB.GetSelectedCardCount();

vm.x = App.selectedCardCount.Value.ToString("N0") + " x ";
```

Comment: Thanks Grant.  Regarding the if statement that I also use in other areas of the code for selectedCardCount.  Any advantage in using the HasValue vs == null?

Answer (score 1):

```
vm.x = App.selectedCardCount?.ToString("N0") + "x";
```

Or:

```
vm.x = App.selectedCardCoun.Value.ToString("N0") + "x";
```